# what will happen if I do not call adapter.stopListening in firebase recycler options

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

What side effect will happen to my app if I do not call **adapter.stopListening();** in firebase recycler options. But I will call only **adapter.startListening();**.

Sample Code Here...

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Photo Here..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't call `stopListening()` the adapter will keep listening for changes to the database, even when the user can't see them anymore. At the very least this results in wasted bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, sir ! ! 